How many of JWST's single point failure issues were related to sunshield deployment?
JWST had 344 single point failure possibilities that could have killed the telescope, but I find no indication of how many SPF's had to do with sunshield deployment. Lots of moving parts going a long way!
Another related issue would be could the JWST compensate to minimize the telescope's performance degradation if certain deployment failure(s) occurred such as one wing not fully unfurling or perhaps tearing?

I've added a few tags, feel free to adjust further

One step to an answer: "The unfolding and tensioning of the sunshield involved 139 of Webb’s 178 release mechanisms, 70 hinge assemblies, eight deployment motors, roughly 400 pulleys, and 90 individual cables"  https://www.nasa.gov/news-release/sunshield-successfully-deploys-on-nasas-next-flagship-telescope/
